# Get notifyed at end of animation triggered by getActionBar().hide() & getActionBar().show()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, show-hide

When I hide or show the `ActionBar` with `getActionBar().hide()` or `getActionBar().show()` the action bar (dis)appears in a smooth animation.

Is there a way to get notified once this animation is complete?

Implementing a `OnLayoutChangeListener` doesn't appear to be a good option as `onLayoutChange()` is sometimes also called **during** the animation and there is no way to determine which call is the last and final call.

Comment: What is the specific purpose you need this for?

Comment: When I hide/show the `ActionBar` the usable screen area changes. I have a custom view that fills all available space and displays pre-rendered images. When the available screen area changes I need to re-render the images with the new size. This is costly, done in the background, and uses native code that I cannot interrupt once started. Hence I don't want to do it before the animation has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get notified once this animation is complete?

Yes, but you'll have to use reflection. `ActionBarImpl` [uses an `Animator`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#L121) to monitor the show and hide animation, so you can attach your own [`AnimatorListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) to this `Field` and receive the callback.

Here's an example:

```
private void monitorActionBarAnimation() {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    try {
        // Get the Animator used internally
        final Class<?> actionBarImpl = actionBar.getClass();
        final Field currentAnimField = actionBarImpl.getDeclaredField("mCurrentShowAnim");

        // Monitor the animation
        final Animator currentAnim = (Animator) currentAnimField.get(actionBar);
        currentAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // Do something
            }

        });
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Just make sure you use it after you call `ActionBar.show` or `ActionBar.hide` because it isn't initialized before those calls. Also, it's released in `AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd` so you'll need to call it each time.

Comment: Works like a charm. Perfect! Thanks for the great example code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActionBar.getHeight()` to find out the height of the action bar, and when your layout height grows by that many pixels you know the animation has finished.

Alternatively, when `ActionBar.getHeight()` returns 0, you know the action bar is hidden.

Comment: This is a simple solution but I would consider this a hack :-).